# Using KVC to get a list of objects' properties

Tags: objective-c, kvc

In this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17387553/objective-c-kvc-collection-accessor-patterns-for-to-many-properties-how-can-i), the chosen answer uses the syntax below to get a list of frequentFlyerNumbers from a list of passengers this way.

> NSArray *frequentFlyerNumbers =
>   someFlight.passengers.frequentFlyerNumbers;

How is this possible given that passengers is an array and compiler can't infer the type that goes into the array?

I got the following error when implementing passengers.

> Property 'frequentFlyerNumbers' not found on object of type
>   'NSMutableArray *'

Comment: it can send a message to valueForKey: to any object, it is up to the object to respond to that correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The answer you cite is poorly written. The code as presented there won't work.

Dot-syntax, in plain code, is just shorthand for an accessor: `someFlight.passengers` means `[someFlight passengers]`, which from the context appears to return a NSMutableArray. NSMutableArray of course doesn't have a frequentFlyerNumbers property itself.

To get the effect you want, do something like this:

```
NSArray *frequentFlyerNumbers = [someFlight valueForKeyPath:@"passengers.frequentFlyerNumbers"];
```

This will work, and return an array of frequentFlyerNumbers. When there's an array or set along a key path, it "projects" the subsequent path across all members of that array or set, producing an array or set of the results.